# Accessing and setting array values within structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int sizes[3];
    float **vals[3]; // an array of size 3 of float ** pointers
} mystruct;
```

What I'm trying to do is set these array values in a function that takes a pointer to a `mystruct`.

```
void populateStruct(mystruct *s) {
    int i, j, n;

    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        scanf("%d", &s->sizes[n]);

        // Malloc the float pointers (**vals) based on the scanned sizes
        s->vals[n] = (float **)malloc(s->sizes[n] * sizeof(float *));
        for (i = 0; i < s->sizes[n]; i++)
            s->vals[n][i] = (float *)malloc(s->sizes[n] * sizeof(float));

        // Populate the float "arrays"
        for (i = 0; i < s->sizes[n]; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < s->sizes[n]; j++) {
                scanf("%f", &s->vals[n][i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm using the function in `main`:

```
int main() {
    mystruct *s1;
    populateStructure(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine, but I get a seg fault when I run it. C is not a strong point of mine, so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: i copy pasted that code into my own project and got no errors. sorry.

Comment: can you post more code ? how is this function called ?

Comment: @Tristan Su: I have updated with how I'm using it.

Comment: This should work:int main() {
    mystruct s1;
    populateStructure(&s1);
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you declaring your s structure and how are you passing it?

In your function where you call populateStruct you should probably declare s:

as `mystruct s and call populateStruct(&s)`

or

```
mystruct *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
populateStruct(s);
```

Comment: I have updated the question to show how I'm using the function in main.

Comment: What you suggested works, but I would appreciate an explanation as to why my method of using the function doesn't work and yours does.

Comment: the problem is that you didn't allocate memory for you pointer in main

Comment: Or `mystruct s; populateStruct(&s);`, which would make more sense for the small snippets here.  Remember, `malloc` is not the only form of memory allocation!  Fight those bad habits from lesser languages.  :-)

Comment: You're not allocating it right.  You're allocating enough for a `mystruct` pointer, not the structure itself.  It should either be `malloc(sizeof(mystruct))` or `malloc(sizeof *s)`.  Otherwise you're opening yourself up to a whole bunch of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
mystruct *s1;
```

s1 is only a pointer with unpredictable value. You didn't allocate memory for the struct you need. 
Dereferencing a wild (uninitialized) pointer would cause segv.
You can modify your code to either:

```
    mystruct s1;
    populateStructure(&s1);
```

or

```
    mystruct *s1 = (mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    populateStructure(s1);
```

( don't forget to free s1 in the second one)

Comment: You mean to not declare a pointer in your first example right?  ;)